# Ordenar un ArrayList de String con numeros, ordenarlo en base a los numeros

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema, no sabría cómo ordenar una lista de Strings. No quiero ordenarlo alfabéticamente, quiero ordenarlo de mayor a menor o de menor a mayor.

```
String line = "hello" + "world" + "54";
    String line1 = "red" + "color" + "895";
    String line2 = "blue" + "color" + "98";
    String line3 = "pink" + "color" + "802";
    lis.add(line);
    lis.add(line1);
    lis.add(line2);
    lis.add(line3);
```

y la salida:

> hello world 54
>   blue color 98
>   pink color 802
>   red color 895

y obtener la última línea con el elemento más grande, en este caso: color rojo 895
Para esto pensé en usar un for, pero no se como podría ponerlo.
Y una vez que consigas la línea, solo imprimir la primera palabra.

red color 895 .

resultado : red

Comment: Ufff, el problema es que estás metiendo el valor numérico todo junto con las letras. ¿No has pensando en una estructura más ordenada que separe las descripciones por un lado y los valores numéricos por otro lado?  Así podrías ordenar por los valores numéricos sacando al mismo tiempo la descripción asociada a ese valor. Si tiene que ser como lo tienes ahora tendrás que pasar por un procedimiento algo oscuro que consistiría en buscar  y extrear el valor numérico dentro del texto, meterlo en alguna parte y luego ordenar en base a eso. O sea, organizar la estructura por programación.

Comment: O sea, al leer que quieres los datos en este orden: `hello world 54 / blue color 98 / pink color 802 / red color 895` yo interpreto que quieres ordenar por los valores `54,98,802,895`. ¿He entendido bien?

Comment: Qué pasaría si pongo `"green"+"color"+"38557223592938857272233030225757223"`? y qué pasaría si pongo `"5433858"+"testing"+"5522dga43"`?

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso sería mucho mejor guardar los datos en un `TreeMap`, el cual de forma natural va ordenando los valores que que se introducen en él.

El `TreeMap` permite guardar valores asociados mediante clave->valor. Para asegurar un orden adecuado, la clave debería ser numérica (`Integer`) y el valor una cadena (`String`).

El `TreeMap` se declararía y llenaría así:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> mMap = new TreeMap<>();
mMap.put(54,"hello" + " world");
mMap.put(895,"red" + " color");
mMap.put(98,"blue" + " color");
mMap.put(802,"pink" + " color");
```

Si imprimes este objeto podrás ver que los datos están en orden, a pesar de que se introdujeron sin ningún orden previo:

```
System.out.println("Valores del TreeMap: "+mMap);
```

**Salida:**

```
Valores del TreeMap: {54=hello world, 98=blue color, 802=pink color, 895=red color}
```

Obtener el último elemento también es muy fácil, `TreeMap` tiene un método `lastEntry()` que sirve para obtener la última entrada, y puedes usar `getValue()` para obtener su valor. Luego, puedes hacer un split del dato para encontrar la primera palabra, por ejemplo:

```
    /*Ahora obtenemos la última entrada con lastEntry()*/
    String lastValue=mMap.lastEntry().getValue();
    /*
        Usamos un ternario para determinar si hay varios valores separados por espacio
        obteniendo el primero de ellos en ese caso
    */
    String firstWord=lastValue.contains(" ") ? lastValue.split(" ")[0] : lastValue;       
    System.out.println("Primera palabra de la última entrada: " + firstWord);
```

**Salida:**

```
Primera palabra de la última entrada: red
```

Si por alguna causa no puedes llenar el `TreeMap` como se indica más arriba, aquí hay una forma de trabajar la cadena, separarla y llenar el `TreeMap`. Aquí pasamos cada valor al método `splitData()` para que él haga el trabajo y el código sea menos repetitivo.

Aquí el método y el `TreeMap` son `static` porque hice la prueba dentro de la clase principal. Si no es tu caso puedes declarar los métodos como no estáticos.

```
private static TreeMap<Integer, String> mMap;
public static void main(String args[])
{

    mMap = new TreeMap<>();        
    splitData("hello" + " world" + "54");
    splitData("red" + " color" + "895");
    splitData("blue" + " color" + "98");
    splitData("pink" + " color" + "802");

    /* Podemos comprobar que el TreeMap está de por sí ordenado*/
    System.out.println("Valores del TreeMap: "+mMap);

    /*Ahora obtenemos la última entrada con lastEntry()*/
    String lastValue=mMap.lastEntry().getValue();
    /*
        Usamos un ternario para determinar si hay varios valores separados por espacio
        obteniendo el primero de ellos en ese caso
    */
    String firstWord=lastValue.contains(" ") ? lastValue.split(" ")[0] : lastValue;       
    System.out.println("Primera palabra de la última entrada: " + firstWord);

}

private static void splitData(String s )
{
    /*Este regex divide la palabra entre cadenas y dígitos*/
    String[] part = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    /*Parseamos el dígito a entero, así no fallará el orden*/
    int k=Integer.parseInt(part[1]);    
    mMap.put(k,part[0]);    
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Valores del TreeMap: {54=hello world, 98=blue color, 802=pink color, 895=red color}
Primera palabra de la última entrada: red
```

Eso es todo. Si tienes alguna duda puedes preguntar en comentarios. Espero te sirva.